# error: cannot use ‘typeid’ with -fno-rtti

Tags: c++, makefile, llvm, rtti, gold-linker

I haven't passed any flag like -fno-rtti.

http://blog.binpang.me/2018/09/27/llvm-gold/
I'm following this link.

```
mkdir build
cd build
../binutils/configure --enable-gold=default --enable-plugins --disable-werror
make all-gold
```

```
cmake ../llvm -DLLVM_BINUTILS_INCDIR="path/to/binutils/include"
make -j$(nproc)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/arena.h:641:25: error: cannot use ‘typeid’ with -fno-rtti
         AllocateAligned(RTTI_TYPE_ID(T), sizeof(T) * num_elements));
```

Comment: Consider changing `"path/to/binutils/include"` to the actual path to `binutils/include`.

Comment: Done that already.

Comment: It's not clear from the question: are you building LLVMgold in a separate build tree from the one you used for binutils?  (You should be.)